# History not accessible from react-router-modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, reactstrap

Hello I'm having a problem with setting 'react-router-modal' parentPath for the last used component

ModalRoute and ModalContainer are a part of 
[react-router-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-modal)

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Navbar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/main" component={ContentDefault} />
              <Route path="/search" component={SearchScreen} />
              <ModalRoute
                path="/register"
                parentPath="/"
                component={RegisterScreen}
              />
              <Route path="/contact" component={ContentDefault} />
              <Route component={ContentDefault} />
            </Switch>
            <ModalContainer />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <Footer />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SearchScreen.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class SearchScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>SearchScreen</h1>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SearchScreen);
```

For Example i'm on mainScreen then i move to  the SearchScreen then i open modal from navbar. I need my modal to go back to the SearchScreen

Answer (score 1):

I found couple of solutions which may help you.

You can try with this:

1. Create state prevPath
2. Add componentWillReceiveProps
3. Provide prevPath state to the parentPath with condition if prevPath is empty redirect me on route '/'

   ```
   class App extends Component {
     state = { 
       prevPath: ''
      }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
        this.setState({ prevPath: this.props.location })
      }
     }

    <ModalRoute
      path="/register"
      parentPath={this.state.prevPath || '/'}
      component={RegisterScreen}
     />
   ```

This is one of the solutions we can try later another one if this doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah but I need it inside of modal, to get the component path from witch I opened modal  as "parentPath"

Comment: Ok, this ModalRoute is component which you created or you are calling that component from another library?

Comment: Sorry for lack of information , it's a part of react-router-modal https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-modal

Comment: I update my answer with the solution which maybe is good, I am not sure.